# Web sockety при смене канала

Tags: сокет, websocket, wifi

Что будет с вэб сокетом если сменится источник интернета к примеру c LTE на Wi Fi, ведь поменяется ip и сервер потеряет связь. Продумано ли это как то в спецификации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При смене сети произойдёт обрыв соединения, данная ситуация может быть обработана в методе `onerror`.

Данный интерфейс вызывается при возникновении ошибок, за ним следует вызов метода `onclose`.

Таким образом можно организовать переподключение, в случае возникновении ошибок.

Comment: А как насчет ситуации когда кто из промежуточных поменял айпи адрес, будь то провайдер или домашний модем?

Comment: Сервер с динамическим IP? Это как-то ненадёжно. Однако очевидно если такая проблема возникает, где-то должно быть место единое место, куда сервер может записать свой новый адрес, а клиент прочитать его, но это должно быть неизменяемое извне место, возможно какое-то стороннее файловое хранилище.

Comment: почему же, сижу в корпоративной сети пользуюсь вэб сокетом, корпоративный сервер захотел поменять статический айпи адрес и поменял, почему бы нет или я что то не допонимаю?

Comment: Захотел поменять статический IP адрес, зачем это понадобилось? Не понимаю, вашей структуры сети. Обычно IP адреса внутри корпоративной сети закрепляются за конкретными устройствами, не встречал, чтобы происходила смена.

Comment: поменять именно внешний айпи адрес внешнего прокси сервера, не внутренний

Comment: Ну так это тем более странно

Comment: это не странно, так происходить может же, соответственно и происходит(возможно я ошибаюсь, поправьте меня), и вопрос то не в этом, а что предлагает на такой случай спецификация вэбсокета

Comment: Спецификация вебсокетов такую ситуацию не предусматривает. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455

Comment: Хотя могу ошибаться